# Is a singleton component in phalcon a real singleton?

Tags: php, phalcon

Let me declare the question:
As far as I know, when a request end, php will clear objects and other data that it created.

But as the Phalcon's document said:
"*[Services can be registered as “shared” services this means that they always will act as singletons. Once the service is resolved for the first time the same instance of it is returned every time a consumer retrieve the service from the container](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/di.html#shared-services)*".

```
<?php
//Register the session service as "always shared"
$di->set('session', function() {
    //...
}, true);
```

What I want to know is that: after a shared component was created, then at the next request, phalcon will reuse the shared component? I means phalcon will not create a new component instance.

Comment: Each request is a separate world, where all the libraries are re-loaded and objects recreated.

Comment: So you mean it is not a real singleton that every request need to create the same component?

Comment: Yes, that is true for every object you create in an http request, nothing new here. "Singleton" is always meant in the context of the same request.

Comment: PHP relays in a [shared nothing architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_nothing_architecture). But I hope that Phalcon/Zephir can change this scenario some day :)

Comment: Well, I have already made sure that it was a singleton in the context of one request. Everything would be created in different requests.

Answer (score 1):

For `DI:setShared()` and your example, **yes** it will meet the conditions of singleton. In opposite, if you `DI::set(..., ..., false)` it will create new instance with every `DI::get(...)` - except when you retrieve it with `DI::getShared()`, what will create new instance based on derived closure and save it to `DI` for future usage - but than you always need `DI::getShared()` as shown below:

```
// not shared
$di->set('test', function() {
    $x = new \stdClass();
    $x->test1 = true;

    return $x;
}, false);

// first use creates singletonized instance
$x = $di->getShared('test');
$x->test2 = true; // writing to singleton

// retrieving singletoned instance
var_dump($di->getShared('test'));

// getting fresh instance
var_dump($di->get('test'));

// despite of previous ::get(), still a singleton
var_dump($di->getShared('test'));
```

and proofs of concept:

```
object(stdClass)[25]
  public 'test1' => boolean true
  public 'test2' => boolean true

object(stdClass)[26]
  public 'test1' => boolean true

object(stdClass)[25]
  public 'test1' => boolean true
  public 'test2' => boolean true
```

To proof how many instances you have created, I suggest declaring destructors in your service to show some output. Anyway there are things used by PHP, that in some cases may remain after request ends - like opened SQL connections.

Comment: Well, I have already made sure that it was a singleton in the context of one request. Everything would be created in different requests.

Comment: For restoring components from previous request you have cache and sessions.